# Ошибка в конвертации MyString

Tags: c++

Выдает ошибку в main()

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

```
#include <cstring>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class MyString
    {
    public:

    void set_len(int len)
        {
            length=len;
        }

    int get_len()
        {
            return length;
        }   
    //конструктор без параметров
    MyString()
    {
    str = nullptr;
    length = 0;
    }

    //конструктор с параметрами, при создании объекта класса необходимо перелать строку которую он будет хранить
    MyString(const char *str)
    {

    length = strlen(str);// функция strlen получает количество символов в строке которую мы передаём в объект

    // выделяем память для динамического массива где будет храниться наша строка 
    // +1 символ так как нужно место в массиве под терминирующий 0
    this->str = new char[length + 1];

    // копируем символы строки в массив нашего класса
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    this->str[i] = str[i];
    }

    //закрываем строку терминирующим нулём
    this->str[length] = '\0';

    }
    // деструктор, отвечает за освобождение ресурвов занятых объектом, вызывается при уничтожении объекта класса
    ~MyString()
    {
    delete[] this->str;
    }

    // конструктор копировании, необходим для создании точной копи объекта класса но в другой области памяти
    MyString(const MyString &other)
    {
    length = strlen(other.str);
    this->str = new char[length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    this->str[i] = other.str[i];
    }

    this->str[length] = '\0';
    }

    // перегруженый оператор присваивания, вызывается когда необходимо присвоить значение одного объекта другому
    MyString& operator =(const MyString &other)
    {
    // здесь логика похожа на ту которая реализована в конструкторе, за исключением того, что нам нужно позаботиться
    // об освобождении ресурсов объекта если до копирования в него новой строки он уже содержал код 
    //+ страндартный синтаксис перегрузки оператора =
    if (this->str != nullptr)
    {
    delete[] str;
    }

    length = strlen(other.str);
    this->str = new char[length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    this->str[i] = other.str[i];
    }

    this->str[length] = '\0';

    return *this;

    }

    //перегруженный оператор сложения, в текущей реализации класса String необходим для конкатенации строк
    MyString operator+(const MyString &other)
    {
    //создаём новый пустой объект где будим хранить результат конкатенации строк и который будет результатом работы
    // перегруженного оператора +
    MyString newStr;
    // получаем количество символов в обеих строках для конкатенации

    int thisLength = strlen(this->str);
    int otherLength = strlen(other.str);

    newStr.length = thisLength + otherLength;

    // выделяем место в динамической памяти под новую строку
    newStr.str = new char[thisLength + otherLength + 1];

    //копируем данные из 2х конкатенируемых строк в новую строку
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < thisLength; i++)
    {
    newStr.str[i] = this->str[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < otherLength; j++, i++)
    {
    newStr.str[i] = other.str[j];
    }

    newStr.str[thisLength + otherLength] = '\0';

    // возвращаем результат конкатенации
    return newStr;
    }

    // выводит строку в консоль, в идеале для этого необходима перегрузка оператора «
    void Print()
    {
    cout << str;
    }

    int Length()
    {
    return length;
    }

    bool operator ==(const MyString & other)
    {
    if (this->length != other.length)
    {
    return false;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
    {
    if (this->str[i] != other.str[i])
    {
    return false;
    }
    }
    return true;
    }

    /*
    bool operator ==(const MyString& other, const char& chars)
    {
        return MyString.chars == chars;
    }
    */


    bool operator !=(const MyString & other) 
    {
    return !(this->operator==(other));
    }

    char& operator [](int index) 
    {
    return this->str[index];
    }

    MyString(MyString &&other) 
    { 
    this->length = other.length; 
    this->str = other.str; 
    other.str = nullptr; 
    } 

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyString& t);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyString& t);
    void get_input (std::istream& in);
    int length; 
    private: 
    // Указатель на массив char, хранит символы, которые мы передали в наш объект. 
    char *str; 
    //int length; 
    }; 
    void MyString::get_input (std::istream& in)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            char c = in.get ();

            if (c == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }

            if (length == 0)
            {
                length = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                ++length;
            }

            char* newStr = new char[length];
            if (str != NULL)
            {
                strcpy (newStr, str);
            }
            newStr[length-2] = c;
            newStr[length-1] = '\0';

            delete[] str;

            str = newStr;
        }
    }


    std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyString& t)
    {
        t.get_input (in);
        return in;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyString& t)
    {
        out << t.str;
        return out;
    }

bool operator == (char, const MyString&);

    int main()
{


//здесь я хочу реализовать функцию поиска
  MyString c;

    cin>>c;


    for (size_t i = 0; i < det_name.size(); i++) 
    {
  if (det_name[i].get_len() < 1) continue;
  if (det_name[i][0] == c) cout << det_name[i] << endl;
    }   

copy( det_name.begin(), det_name.end(), ostream_iterator<MyString>(cout, 'c'));

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Между делом, объявленные методы внутри определения класса всегда будут безропотно выполнятся **inline**. Всё это приведёт к разбухания кода по размеру без предупреждения компилятора. Рекомендую вынести определения методов из класса с добавлением предлога **inline**.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю здесь ошибка

```
MyString c;
cin>>c;
```

Попробуйте так:

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
MyString c( str.c_str() );
```

Comment: Проблема осталась,ошибку выдает на строке copy( det_name.begin(), det_name.end(), ostream_iterator<MyString>(cout, 'c'));